# Can't connect to a server(Google Virtual Machine)

Tags: ssh, server, google-compute-engine

I've recently experienced a problem with connection to my server after rebooting it. Moreover, I tried to create a new one based on a snapshot I've made, but I wasn't able to connect to it too.

When trying to connect using web ssh user interface I see: **We are unable to connect to the VM on port 22.**

Connection trough command line gives this: **ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code [255]**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that helped me was to create an additional instance and attach disk from previous one to it. Then I was able to connect to a new instance and mount an old disk to copy files from it.